# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, storage

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))"

Recently got this error when starting a debug of my ASP.NET MVC project.
Just out of the blue, haven't touched any of Azure files or configs, or added something since my last succesfull build.

Read this thread but it didn't provide the correct solution for my error:

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772858/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windowsazure-diagnostics-or-one-of-i)

Not sure what kind of files I should display and what parts are imporant. Please someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running Fusion Log ([Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to determine which dependent assembly is missing (or if the application actually can't find the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage for some reason).

Edit: quick tutorial from Hansleman that should get people on the right track: [Back to Basics: Using Fusion Log Viewer to Debug Obscure Loader Errors](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

Comment: I got it started, but I can't find a tutorial for how to use it properly? Can't seem to associate it with my project..

Comment: Either way I deleted the Azure project connected to the solution and removed the references since I only needed it for some debugging. I aprove of your answer though since it was leading me in a correct path to correcting the issue. Thanks for assistance.